# C# XElement - add element before value of existing element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have an XML string like this:

```
<para>Some text in here</para>
```

and i need to add another element just after the opening para tag, so that it reads

```
<para><title>My Title</title>Some text in here</para>
```

I've tried this but it doesn't give me what i need:

```
content.Descendants("para") 
               .LastOrDefault()
               .Add(new XElement("title", "My Title"));
```

The problem with this is that it adds the `<title>` element and its contents to just before the closing `<para>` tag.

How can i get it where i want it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string xml = "<para>Some text in here</para>";
            XElement para = XElement.Parse(xml);

            para.AddFirst(new XElement("title", "My Title"));
```